# passing C++ objects to CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, object, cuda

I have a piece of code which consists of objects which I do not have the permission to modify. On the other hands I have to write CUDA kernel for doing some computations. At the moment I am converting the required information into an array or struct and passing it. Is it possible to pass objects as such to CUDA kernel and is there any way for CUDA kernel to access  private members of the class. Some people have also suggested thrust to me.

Comment: Consult [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119245/1593077) to a related question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use c++ functionality in your CUDA code. It has some additional requirements. For example kernel function can't me a member of class. For usage you own data structures it need to fit some requirements.

- Members that you need to use in device code should be annotated as `__device__`
- You need to implement `__device__` constructors.
- If your structure encapsulate pointer this need to be allocated in device memory.
- You can use templates, but you can't use classes with virtual functions.

You can see some examples of c++ data structures in programming guide Appendix D. C/C++ Language Support.

As for your concrete questions:

1. Yes, you can pass objects in kernel. You need to implement `__device__` copy-constructor for it.
2. You can access private members in class methods. You should implement `__device__` accessor method to use it outside class. **But** you can't pass class with private member through kernel call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. I still have a doubt regarding the main query. Suppose I have a c++ class ex:- class A(){private : int x;}. Now I pass an object of this class to cuda kernel in a different file. Now how can this kernel access the private variable. I have to include the class definition for the kernel for it to understand. But then I get the error that it is inaccessible.If I include __global__ function() in the class definition then g++ cannot compile it. How to go about it.

Comment: I have a c++ file fil1.c with a header file1.h which has the definition of a class - class A{private : int x; void funct();}. In the funct function which is implemented in file1.c I call a function in a file2.cu say B() and I pass to B an object objx of class A. Now B() calls a cuda kernel K<<<1,1000>>>(objxDev) where objxDev is an object of class A and malloced on the device side with proper memcpy. problem is that within the kernel code I query the objx.x and I get error that it is inaccessible. I have to give this kernel function the power of accessing private member x withot afftg class A.

Comment: Yuo should to implement you class data structures in CUDA .cu files or .h, .hpp, .cuh header files